# Solutions to the following equation including a Mobius function

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, algorithms, mobius-function

Let $\mu$ be the Mobius function. Now, how would one solve the following equation with respect to the variables $a\in \mathbb{N}$ and $b\in \mathbb{N}$?

$\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\mu(d)\lfloor \frac{a}{d}\rfloor\lfloor \frac{b}{d}\rfloor = a\cdot b$?

Alternatively, how could we find the local maximums and minimums of the function $\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\mu(d)\lfloor \frac{a}{d}\rfloor\lfloor \frac{b}{d}\rfloor$ with respect to $a$ or $b$ when we actually know the other variable? Can we do this by differentiation?  Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: This is an interesting summation.  Where did you encounter it?  Does it have any special meaning or other context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the questions you asked can be answered with the exact formula
\begin{align*}
\sum_{d=1}^\infty \mu(d) \lfloor \tfrac ad \rfloor \lfloor \tfrac bd \rfloor
&= \sum_{d=1}^\infty \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{m\le a \\ d\mid m}} 1 \sum_{\substack{n\le b \\ d\mid n}} 1 \\
&= \sum_{m\le a} \sum_{n\le b} \sum_{\substack{d\ge 1 \\ d\mid m \\ d\mid n}} \mu(d) \\
&= \sum_{m\le a} \sum_{n\le b} \sum_{\substack{d\ge 1 \\ d\mid\gcd(m,n)}} \mu(d) = \sum_{m\le a} \sum_{\substack{n\le b \\ \gcd(m,n)=1}} 1.
\end{align*}
(Definitely avoid differentiation with functions that aren't even continuous.)